# Align face with a vertex via python

Tags: python, scripting

Hi and good days to everyone.

What I have been trying to accomplish is rotating the plane (in the image below) in its x (red) direction until it aligns with the top vertex of the cone. Is there a way for me accomplish this via scripting? My tryouts have given me no result.

Edit: I have added a picture how it should look. And top of the cone is just a point. It could be 3d cursor.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you mean the _normal_ of the plane should _point_ to that cone vertex? or?

Comment: Rotating around what?

Comment: @Maxx, Origin point of plane. It's shown in first picture.

Comment: Ok. Why do you need it via scripting? Are you assuming it can't be done otherwise? Or do you really need it via scripting (for instance, you are developing an addon)?

Comment: @Maxx, No I am trying to automatise a process that I do everyday by hand. :)

Comment: OK ! And can you assume the the direction of the plane is one of the three local axis of your plane's object?

Comment: And if not, can you assume that the plane's object contains only a plane (single face object)?

Comment: And last question, how could you specify which point you want to touch? Is it a single point in a vertex group? Do you already have the coordinate available in your script? Anything? ;)

Comment: Ah and also : when you do it by hand, what is your workflow? You just do it with your mouth by getting as close as you can, or have you find a better way to do it with no guess work? (if you have, it would be nice to simply automate your already working workflow). Can I assume that if you do it by hand, you do not need to do it on a very large amount of objects, and that you don't mind if the process takes a few extra milliseconds?

Comment: 1- It's stated in main post. Just rotate "x" axis. 2- Yes. 3- Spesified point is a world space in script. So it is known. I just wanted to make it visual.

Comment: @Maxx, I don't believe this is related but part of my work is cutting 3d models into smaller printable parts. I just need to rotate planes used for cuts on just x axis. That will make my work easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. 
I'll just show a workflow for doing it with constraints and blender operators. 
I assume you will manage to code the same process in python?

I add an empty which is the point you want to track. I had a child cone for consistency with your image ;-).

[image]

I add another empty with a set of contraints :

[image]

And then I add a constraint to the plane's object :

[image]

It is over, the plane is like you want. 
Now you can either leave it as is. You can move the first empty, and the plane will follow it. 
Or, you can select your plane, and "Apply visual transform". And then you can delete everything you don't want anymore.

[image]

Now you can do these steps in python ! I guess it is slower than computing directly the good rotation with some trigonometry, but it has the avantage og being simple, plus you can still move your point at the end !

Comment: I didn't know how to put a point with directions, so I used a cone :D